# Connect to Docker Compose SQL Server from Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer and save database to local PC

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, docker-compose

Two questions:

- Is it possible to connect to Docker Compose SQL Server from Visual Studio's **SQL Sever Object Explorer**? If so, how?
- Visual Studio 2019 usually saves the local databases into `C:\Users\Username\ProjectName.mdf`. Can I make docker-compose save it on my local PC instead of the Linux docker? For example in `C:\SkybotDb`.

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    container_name: skybotdb
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "SkybotPassword123456"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - webnet

  skybot.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}skybotweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Skybot.Web/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://0.0.0.0:5001
      - "UseInMemoryDatabase=true"
      - "ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=db;Database=SkybotDb;User=sa;Password=SkybotPassword123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
      - ElasticConfiguration__Uri=http://es01:9200
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 5001:5001
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - db
      - es01

  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - webnet

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.10.1
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - webnet

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local

networks:
  webnet:
    driver: bridge
```

#### Skybot.Web.Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Skybot.Web/Skybot.Web.csproj", "src/Skybot.Web/"]
COPY ["src/Skybot.Application/Skybot.Application.csproj", "src/Skybot.Application/"]
COPY ["src/Skybot.Domain/Skybot.Domain.csproj", "src/Skybot.Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Skybot.Infrastructure/Skybot.Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Skybot.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Skybot.Web/Skybot.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Skybot.Web"
RUN dotnet build "Skybot.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Skybot.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Skybot.Web.dll"]
```